# Alter SQL Server columns with dependencies on Index

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with some indexes and they are dependent on some columns.

These columns are of type `smallint` and I want to alter them to `decimal`.

Here is the question: if I alter the columns, does it effect the index performance?

(I know I can't alter the columns with dependencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altering the datatype of the column will Rebuild the indexes as well. So your index performance wouldn't be affected.